# Draggable div in td in table vuejs

Tags: vue.js, html-table, draggable

I want to drag divs between tds in tabe with Vue  draggable.
I wrote

```
 <template>


 <div class="row">
<div class="col-8">
  <h3>Draggable table</h3>

  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Id</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Sport</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
   <draggable v-model="list" tags="div"  @start="drag = true"
  @end="drag = false">
      <tr v-for="item in list" :key="item.name">
        <td scope="row"><div class="item">{{ item.id }}</div></td>
        <td><div class="item">{{ item.name }}</div></td>
        <td><div class="item">{{ item.sport }}</div></td>
      </tr>
    </draggable>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
<script>
```

but divs cannot be drag.
how can I drag divs in between td in table??
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you just missed to include your current approach or don't have one yet. Searched a bit in your request and found something for you to start with.

[How TO - Create a Draggable HTML Element](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp)

A div is used in this example. Maybe this will help you.